# How to display 3 different Lists next to each other in SAP UI 5?

Tags: css, flexbox, sapui5

I've 3 different  Lists that I want to display next to each other, however for some reason they are being displayed under each other.

I am using JSViews.

Here is the relevant parts of my code and screenshot ;

in my JSView ;

```
    var keysList = new sap.m.List(this.createId("keysList"), {

    });
    var valList1 = new sap.m.List(this.createId("valList1"), {

    });
    var valList2 = new sap.m.List(this.createId("valList2"), {

    });
    var vBox2 = new sap.m.VBox({
        alignItems: "Start",
        justifyContent: "Start",
        items: [
            keysList,
            valList1,
            valList2
        ]
    }).addStyleClass("vbox2");

    var oPageMerkliste2 = new sap.m.Page({
        showHeader: false,
        content: [
            toolbar,
            vBox1,
            vBox2
        ]
    });

    return oPageMerkliste2;
```

my Controller ;

```
        var keysList = this.byId("keysList");
        var keysModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        keysModel.setData(keysObj);          
        console.log("keysList", keysList);
        keysList.setModel(keysModel);
        var template0 = new sap.m.CustomListItem({
            content: [
                new sap.m.VBox({
                    items: [
                        new sap.m.Text({
                            text : "{}"
                        })
                    ]
                }).addStyleClass("listSize")
            ]
        }).addStyleClass("");
        keysList.bindAggregation("items", "/", template0);
        //val list 1 
        var valList1 = this.byId("valList1");
        var valList1Model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        valList1Model.setData(valsObj1);          
        console.log("valList1", valList1);
        valList1.setModel(valList1Model);
        var template1 = new sap.m.CustomListItem({
            content: [
                new sap.m.VBox({
                    items: [
                        new sap.m.Text({
                            text : "{}"
                        })
                    ]
                }).addStyleClass("listSize")
            ]
        }).addStyleClass("");
        valList1.bindAggregation("items", "/", template1);
            //val2 list  
        var valList2 = this.byId("valList2");
        var valList2Model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        valList2Model.setData(valsObj2);          
        console.log("valList2", valList2);
        valList2.setModel(valList2Model);
        var template2 = new sap.m.CustomListItem({
            content: [
                new sap.m.VBox({
                    items: [
                        new sap.m.Text({
                            text : "{}"
                        })
                    ]
                }).addStyleClass("listSize")
            ]
        }).addStyleClass("");
        valList2.bindAggregation("items", "/", template2);
```

I thought `VBox` was actually for displaying the items next to each other but apparently in my case it doesn't behave in the way it actually should.

I tried to play with it on Chrome Dev. Tools and edited styles with changing width s but it didn't help either.

How can I display them next to each other ?   ( Like 0. index of the first  List is next to 0. index of the second List etc.)

And here is a screenshot how my "List" looks so far  ( sorry about bad paint skills)
[image]

Comment: What is the `flexDirection` value set to?

Comment: You are using VBox, they will be in Vertical, try changing it to **HBox** (Horizontal)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing VBox with [HBox](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.HBox).

```
sap.m.HBox
```

In your code, your using VBox, so it is  doing the expected.

Comment: obviously you're right,  i should've used google translate before asking it but still thanks. I will try if it works monday